# bash: getting sorted interfaces ip list, without loopback (comma separated)

Tags: bash

I need a script which outputs a sorted, comma separated, ip list of interfaces, not including loopback.

I managed to come up with the following script, which outputs a comma separated ip list of all interfaces:

```
ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}' | awk 'NR%2{printf $0",";next;}1'
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how not to include the loopback and to output a sorted list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not experienced with bash, so this is probably not the simplest, but it works.

```
ip addr show | awk '/inet /{print substr($2,1)}' | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | tail -n +2 | sort | tr -s '\n' ',' | head -c -1
```